# Помогите с workflow PowerShell

Tags: powershell, workflow

Написал упрощенный пример кода на PowerShell. Нам нужно в рабочем процессе вызвать функцию, которая в свою очередь вызывает другую функцию.

```
function FuncSecond {
    Write-Output "This is second func"
}

function FuncFirst {
    Write-Output "This is first func"
    FuncSecond
}

workflow Test-ParallelForeach
{    
    FuncFirst
}

Test-ParallelForeach
```

И когда происходит вызов второй функции возникает ошибка, якобы нет такой функции иди проверь ее наличие, а она есть, как быть? В рабочем коде много таких функций. Нашел один способ избавиться от такой ошибки - это поместить определение функции в функцию, откуда мы ее вызываем, но такой код будет ооочень уродливым. Выдает следующую ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
workflow FuncSecond {
    Write-Output "This is second func"
}

workflow FuncFirst {
    Write-Output "This is first func"
    FuncSecond
}

workflow Test-ParallelForeach
{    
    FuncFirst
}

Test-ParallelForeach
```

Насколько я понимаю код секции обрабатывается не интерпретатором powershell, а Windows Workflow Foundation, я так и не успел войти в эту тему до конца, потому что сейчас больше пишу код на PS версии 7, workflow не поддерживается в .NET Core, и в Powershell с шестой версии.

в седьмой версии у комманделета ForEach-Object появился параметр -Parallel, задачи по распараллеливанию решаю через этом механизм.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj574123(v=ws.11)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]